# Why clicking Run/Debug button on Android Studio absolutely does nothing on specific project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have received source code from a company & work on that. But after importing the project, when I clicked Run/Debug nothing happens. Even gradle building process doesn't start. There is no any errors. I checked manifest & build.gradle dependencies, version, everything seems fine.

Other projects are working fine in same android studio. I generated signed apk & the app runs fine.

After searching previous answers on stackoverflow, I tried following things but nothings worked.

1. Edit run configurations & selected module-> app, default activity.
2. Tried completely making new run configuration.
3. From file, tried Invalidate Cache & restart.
4. Restarted laptop.
5. Started Sdk manager & downloaded all suggested sdk/tools/repository etc. Restarted laptop too.

Can I try to view log or do something like that. Or, is there some other thing which I can try. I want to solve this on my own & dont want to receive help from the code provider. If everything fails, then only I will like to ask their help.

Edit:
Ok I found that, if I remove following gradle awake, make project manually & run then, it is working fine. But, that gave me other problems like no log/print showing on logcat. I deleted & readded gradle-aware make, didn't work. Also, I tried adding app:debugAssemble in task, didn't work. In other projects, simple gradle-aware is working fine.

[image: Gradle Awake before launch]

Comment: can you add screen shot of that

Comment: @Uma , I have edited question. Thanks

Comment: Finally, I uninstalled android studio which was preview version & installed stable version. It is working correctly now.

Comment: Stable version 3.0 on Ubuntu did'e worked too